# Batch programming: randomly goto random parts of the code

Tags: batch-file, cmd

(I will edit or delete this post if i wrote something bad)
So i have this code which i can't seem to pull off correctly. Just look at it.

```
set /a num=%random% %%9 +1
set /p start="Do you want to start? "
if %start% ==yes goto %random%
if %start% ==no exit
:1
echo Tu turi %score% tasku (-us)!
set /p answer="6 x 5 = "
if %answer% equ 30 (
    echo Teisingai! Gavai 1 taska!
    set /a score+=1
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:2
echo Tu turi %score% tasku (-us)!
set /p answer="123 x 3 = "
if %answer% equ 369 (
    echo Teisingai! Gavai 1 taska!
    set /a score+=1
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:3
echo Tu turi %score% tasku (-us)!
set /p answer="-93128 + 993128 = "
if %answer% equ 900000 (
    echo Teisingai! gavai 5 taskus!
    set /a score+=5
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:4
echo Tu turi %score% tasku!
set /p answer="35734534757357 x 0 = "
if %answer% equ 0 (
    echo Teisingai! gavai 2 taskus!
    set /a score+=2
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:5
echo Tu turi %score% tasku!
set /p answer="6 + 8 x 3 = "
if %answer% equ 30 (
    echo Teisingai! gavai 3 taskus!
    set /a score+=3
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:6
echo Tu turi %score% tasku!
set /p answer="X + 1234 = 2468. Koks skaicius yra X?"
if %answer% equ 1234 (
    echo Teisingai! gavai 4 taskus!
    set /a score+=4
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:7
echo Tu turi %score% tasku!
set /p answer="-9 x -9 = "
if %answer% equ 81 (
    echo Teisingai! gavai 5 taskus!
    set /a score+=5
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:8
echo Tu turi %score% tasku!
set /p answer="1 + 1 x (111 x 3) = "
if %answer% equ 666 (
    echo Teisingai! gavai 6 taskus!
    set /a score+=6
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
:9
echo Tu turi %score% tasku!
set /p answer="634745645634576456457645657 x 0 = "
if %answer% equ 0 (
    echo Teisingai! gavai 2 taskus!
    set /a score+=2
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    ) else (
    echo Neteisingai :( Atsakymas buvo %answer%!
    echo %score% > %player%.sav
    )
```

It's mostly in a different language. Sorry. Basically i want to Make it so if you write "yes" at the beginning it would go to a random math question (from 1 to 9). I hope someone will understand this because i'm bad at explaining things :(

Answer (score 2):

Copypasting isn't good for making some piece of logic work on a bunch of different data. You don't need any GOTOs here, just organize your data in a more clever way. Then you can easily pick a random question from your data structure (or generate it on the fly) and put it in a function. OK, this may be too hard to do in CMD language. This is not good language to start with, try something simpler and more powerful. I recommend Scheme or Haskell. After that, learning another language will be easier.

Answer (score 2):

What about `goto:%num%` ?

---

<sub>Please do not enter.</sub>

Comment: Yes, instead of `goto %random%`